# Recursive setTimeout makes stack grow

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack, settimeout

As far as I understood from these two answers:

- [Will a recursive 'setTimeout' function call eventually kill the JS Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779616/4228942)
- [Does use of recursive process.nexttick let other processes or threads work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113244/4228942)

when `setTimeout` is called recursively the stack should not grow but if you open a devtool in either FF or Chrome and run this function:

```js
function recur(n = 10) {
  console.trace();
  console.log(n, '++++++++++++++++');
  if (n > 0) setTimeout(() => recur(--n), 1000);
}

recur()
```

you'll see the following:

```
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
10 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
9 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
8 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
7 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
6 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
5 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
4 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
3 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
2 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
1 ++++++++++++++++ debugger eval code:3:11
console.trace() debugger eval code:2:11
    recur debugger eval code:2
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    recur debugger eval code:4
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    recur debugger eval code:4
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:8
0 ++++++++++++++++
```

Why is that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, do you know how I can confirm this?

Comment: You can observe this by watching memory allocations. Remove the debugger stuff and run `recur(9007199254740991)` with and without `setTimeout`. You will find the interpreter crashing (if it is an interpreter without memory limit you may even find your OS crashing) due to out of memory errors (or even stack overflow) without setTimeout. With setTimeout it would just take a long time to execute but will use a constant amount of memory

Comment: Maybe it's saving the stack *frame descriptions* so they can be traced, but not the *actual frames*, that way GC can happen normally, but the user can still debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asynchronous stack traces in Chrome Developer Tools... designed to keep you sane whilst trying to figure out why your function is in a setTimeout() recursion loop

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

The javascript thread model is the event loop.
- https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/

`setTimeout()` isn't technically recursing. Its an asynchronous function call. Inside the thread, it returns a numeric id synchronously (you can call `clearTimeout()` on it), then as a side effect adds your function to the end of the event-loop stack. Its a singlethreaded model, so once javascript has finished your current thread/event, it will pop the next function off the top of the stack for execution. Thus 1000ms is simply the minimum time for scheduled execution but it might take longer if it is still executing previous events/threads.

If I run this code in node, I get:

```
node
Welcome to Node.js v12.5.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> function recur(n = 10) {
...   console.trace();
...   console.log(n, '++++++++++++++++');
...   if (n > 0) setTimeout(() => recur(--n), 1000);
... }
undefined
> 
> recur()
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at repl:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:123:20)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:384:29)
    at bound (domain.js:415:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:428:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:700:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:205:15)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:314:10)
10 ++++++++++++++++
undefined
> Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
9 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
8 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
7 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
6 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
5 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
4 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
3 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
2 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
1 ++++++++++++++++
Trace
    at recur (repl:2:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (repl:4:31)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
0 ++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.